# Rational Test Workbench - Mobile Testing - Variable RTW_Mobile_App_Selection doesn't work

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mtww, rtw

I’m using Rational Test Workbench (RTW) for automatization of my mobile tests. I want to test only the newest version of my app, so I'm using the test variable RTW_Mobile_App_Selection within my tests.

I'm initializing it with the right value AlwaysUseLatestVersion but the when triggering the test over Rational Quality Manager (RQM) or RTW they always run with the old one. The newest version of the app is available on the workbench.

I’m trying to do it with Android apps. I’m always compiling the app from the same eclipse-project changing only the version and some lines of code. Do I have to set something special on the app side to make it work? How should it work?

Thanks for the help!

**Edit:**
I'm using worklight with android enviroment.

Comment: Be be clear: a Native Android app or a Worklight-based Hybrid app with the Android environment?

Comment: I'm using worklight with android enviroment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a huge mistake testing this feature only with one testsuite. It seems the one I was trying to get it work with was somehow broken and took always version 1.0. I tried it today with another testsuite and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not in silent install mode, you should have first install the new version on your phone/tablet.
Be also care to the case

Comment: I'm using android emulator with silent install on